# Middleware not working correctly after hitting browser 'go back' button for the first time Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a login page and when the user enters their login and password correctly, I redirect them to a dashboard page. I am using Laravel `guest` middleware, so when a logged in user tries to go to login page, they get redirected to dashboard. Everything works fine, except when the user logs in and gets redirected to dashboard, if they hit the browser back button, the login page still shows. It only goes away after a refresh. How can I fix this problem?

Here's my routes:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'guest' ],function() 
{

    Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');

    Route::get('/loadLogin','MainController@loadLogin');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is because the browser caches the previous page? If the user attempted to POST or GET data to the page, the server would redirect them to loadLogin. The only thing the user is really seeing is the client-side code their browser saved, hence why the refresh fixes it.

JCode said check if the user is logged in the controller but controllers are not the place to be checking this.

Comment: Will refreshing the page with JavaScript fix the issue in any way?

Comment: Yes of course but that is unnecessary since you would need to check if the page needs to be refreshed (ie if the user is logged in) using JS and then call the function.

Comment: So you suggest leaving this the way it is?

Comment: Yes, the cached login page that the user sees does not create any problems for your application.

Comment: The problem is that I have the same issue in my profile page. After a user logs out and they push the 'go back' button, they can still see their profile page. In this case I really would like the profile page not to show after a logout.

Comment: Again though, if the user attempts to do anything while logged out (eg edit their account), the server will ignore it and redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if user is logged in inside the index of MainController, if so - redirect to loadLogin.